# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I'm working on a SharePoint server. It was SP2010+SQL2008 R2. I migrated it to SP2013 + SQL2012. Everything worked fine for days. I keep working on it. Then, I find that there is ONE webapp having this problem. When browse to it, it shows below errors.

```
Server Error in '/' Application. 

<nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack> 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 


[DirectoryNotFoundException: <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidID, DateTime& pdtTimeCreated, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, Int32& plSiteFlags, Boolean& pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled, String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& plSiteSchemaMajorVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaMinorVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaBuildVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaRevisionVersion, Int32& puiVersion, Int16& pnClientTag, Boolean& pfIsEvalSite, Guid& pgSourceSiteId, DateTime& pdtExpirationDate, Guid& pgEvalSiteId, Guid& pguidAppInstanceId, String& pbstrRemoteAppUrl, String& pbstrOAuthAppId, String& pbstrAppDatabaseName, Guid& pgAppDatabaseServerReferenceId, String& pbstrAppDatabaseTargetApplicationId, String& pbstrAppWebDomainId, Int32& plUpgradeFlags, DateTime& pdtReminderDate, DateTime& pdtLastContentChange, DateTime& pdtLastSecurityChange, UInt64& pmaskDeny) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidID, DateTime& pdtTimeCreated, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, Int32& plSiteFlags, Boolean& pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled, String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& plSiteSchemaMajorVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaMinorVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaBuildVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaRevisionVersion, Int32& puiVersion, Int16& pnClientTag, Boolean& pfIsEvalSite, Guid& pgSourceSiteId, DateTime& pdtExpirationDate, Guid& pgEvalSiteId, Guid& pguidAppInstanceId, String& pbstrRemoteAppUrl, String& pbstrOAuthAppId, String& pbstrAppDatabaseName, Guid& pgAppDatabaseServerReferenceId, String& pbstrAppDatabaseTargetApplicationId, String& pbstrAppWebDomainId, Int32& plUpgradeFlags, DateTime& pdtReminderDate, DateTime& pdtLastContentChange, DateTime& pdtLastSecurityChange, UInt64& pmaskDeny) +2329
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWebPublic() +1607
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_AppInstanceId() +34
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.RedirectToIsolatedDomainForAppWeb() +94
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.OnPreInit(EventArgs e) +152
   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.IdentityModelSignInPageBase.OnPreInit(EventArgs e) +18
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +40
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1571
```

If I use:

```
    get-spsite | get-spweb
```

It lists the site/web correctly. There are multiple webapp on this server, and only this one webapp has this problem. What can cause this? How to fix it?

What I plan to do is:

1. Detach/retach the content database in the existing webapp;
2. Detach the content database, remove existing webapp, recreate the
   webapp, attach the content database;

What else I should try before I do the above #2?

The thing puzzled me is: why it worked before, then had this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) detach/attach content database, same error.

2) detach content database in the webapp, remove the webapp, **create a new webapp using the same port**, attach content database, **then pray some minutes**, it works! :)

I still do not know what/why caused this, but it is fixed.

Thanks

Comment: In my experience, all the <nativehr> error is caused by unmatching version level. It ususally happen when upgrade from old SP to new. If it works for a few days and not work, you may check whether your servers being patched around the days.